# React.js - add div's on the fly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am getting my hands dirty on React and I can't seem to figure out this simple problem (probably because of lack of sleep)

I want to add elements (or divs) inside the `render` on the fly when I click "Add Row".

How would I go on about it? Do I need to keep it in an array and within the render function, I will have to map it?

```
class SimpleExample extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.handleAddingDivs = this.handleAddingDivs.bind(this)
    }


    handleAddingDivs() {
        const uniqueID = Date.now()
        return (
            <div>
                This is added div! uniqueID: {uniqueID}
            </div>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>These are added divs </h1>

                <button className="btn-anchor-style add-row-link" type="button" onClick={this.handleAddingDivs}>{'Add Row'}</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to add only one div or multiple divs ?

Comment: Multiple divs, as long I press the add row button

Comment: you guessed right, using a array.map is a good way. make sure you keep data in state so auto re-render

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you want to add multiple divs, so maintain a state variable for that, count or any other data (you can use any `array` also and store the unique value of all the divs), then use map or any other loop to create the divs for that.

Check this working snippet:

```js
class SimpleExample extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {count : 0}
        this.handleAddingDivs = this.handleAddingDivs.bind(this)
    }


    handleAddingDivs() {
        this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1})     
    }
    
    renderDivs(){
        let count = this.state.count, uiItems = [];
        while(count--)
           uiItems.push(
               <div>
                   This is added div! uniqueID: {count}
               </div> 
            )
        return uiItems;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>These are added divs </h1>
                <button className="btn-anchor-style add-row-link" type="button" onClick={this.handleAddingDivs}>{'Add Row'}</button>
                {this.renderDivs()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SimpleExample/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id ='app'/>
```

Comment: awesome, this did the trick, and the snippet worked wonderfully. many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below. Whenever you click the button, a unique id is generated and stored in `state.uids`. In `render()`, added divs are rendered according to `state.uids`.

```js
class SimpleExample extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.handleAddingDivs = this.handleAddingDivs.bind(this)
        this.state = {uids:[]}
    }


    handleAddingDivs() {
        let curr = this.state.uids;
        const uniqueID = Date.now()
        this.setState({uids:[...curr, uniqueID]});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>These are added divs </h1>

                <button className="btn-anchor-style add-row-link" type="button" onClick={this.handleAddingDivs}>{'Add Row'}</button>
                { this.state.uids.map((uid, idx)=>
                  <div key={uid}>This is added div! uniqueID: {uid}</div>
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SimpleExample/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id ='app'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you will need to store data about new divs somewhere...

this is what flux/redux is sometimes used for: you store all data you need to render in `Store` and then you know what to render.

But if you whant this using only React, then use state !
Your state should be like this in your case:

```
{
  addedDivs: [
    {uniqueId: 123},
    {uniqueId: 754},
  ]
}
```

then in render you will map it (don't forget to add `key`)

```
this.state.addedDivs.map((item) = > {return (<div key={item.uniqueId}></div>) })
```

and onClick you should just add some, using setState:

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => {
  var addedDivs = prevState.addedDivs;
  var uniqueId = Date.now();
  addedDivs.push({uniqueId: uniqueId});
  return {addedDivs: addedDivs}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking of terms of DOM manipulation/jQuery. When you use React, you need think in terms of data, and how it relates to your DOM.

In your case, you need to:

- Update your component state with a new row, everytime there is a click to the 'Add Row" button, in the `handleAddingDivs()` method
- Render rows based on the state, in the `render()` method

```
class SimpleExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleAddingDivs = this.handleAddingDivs.bind(this)
   }

  //Modify state of component when 'Add Row' button is clicked
  handleAddingDivs() {
    const uniqueID = Date.now();
    this.setState({rows: this.state.rows.concat(uniqueId)});
  }

  //The `render()` function will be executed everytime state changes
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>These are added divs </h1>
        //The rows are rendered based on the state
        {this.state.rows.map(function(uniqueId) {
          return ( 
            <div key={item.uniqueId}>This is added div! uniqueID: {uniqueID}</div>
          )
        }}
        <button className="btn-anchor-style add-row-link" type="button" onClick={this.handleAddingDivs}>{'Add Row'}</button>                  
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```